# prisma seeding , contained an invalid datetime value with either day or month set to zero

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, prisma

I'm currently having trouble with my seeding process, im using prisma, mysql, nodejs and typescript:

```
import { db } from "../src/utils/db.server";

type Role = {
  name: string;
};

async function seed() {
  try {
    await Promise.all(
      getRoles().map((role) => {
        return db.role.create({
          data: {
            name: role.name,
            createDate: new Date(),
          },
        });
      })
    );
    console.log("Seed data successfully inserted.");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error seeding data:", error);
  } finally {
    // Add any cleanup or finalization code here if needed.
  }
}

seed();

function getRoles(): Array<Role> {
  return [
    {
      name: "Engineer",
    },
    {
      name: "Customer Care",
    },
    {
      name: "Business Developer",
    },
  ];
}
```

I try changing the code, setting the date to 0000-00-00 format i tried undefined and even change mymysql mode all seems to fail with the same error.

here is my prisma schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("BASE_URL")
}

model Role {
  id           Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name         String         @db.VarChar(45)
  createDate   DateTime       @db.DateTime(6)
  updatedDate  DateTime       @default(dbgenerated("'0000-00-00 00:00:00'")) @db.DateTime(0)
  deletedDate  DateTime       @default(dbgenerated("'0000-00-00 00:00:00'")) @db.DateTime(0)
  serviceToken ServiceToken[]
  users        User[]
}

model ServiceToken {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String   @db.VarChar(45)
  token       String   @db.VarChar(255)
  createDate  DateTime @db.DateTime(6)
  updatedDate DateTime @default(dbgenerated("'0000-00-00 00:00:00'")) @db.DateTime(0)
  deletedDate DateTime @default(dbgenerated("'0000-00-00 00:00:00'")) @db.DateTime(0)
  roleId      Int
  role        Role     @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])

  @@index([roleId], map: "ServiceToken_roleId_fkey")
}

model User {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email      String   @unique @db.VarChar(45)
  name       String   @db.VarChar(45)
  password   String   @db.VarChar(255)
  roleId     Int
  createDate DateTime
  updateDate DateTime
  deleteDate DateTime
  role       Role     @relation(fields: [roleId], references: [id])

  @@index([roleId], map: "User_roleId_fkey")
}
```

I have search for solutions in giothub the documentation and even blogs but nothing seems to work.